# Counting different ways to create QR code

Tags: combinations, combinatorics, counting

I am working on an app that needs to create QR-code through a code, essentialy as for now
I thought on generating something similar to a sudoku board (9X9 squares of 3X3 sections) s.t. every odd number is beeing painted black and every double number is being painted in white.

I am stuck not on a code but rather on trying to figure out how many DIFFERENT options do I have to create images in that manner as for now - 
For every 3X3 section I have (9 choose 5) options to place black "tiles" and I have 9 of those
which makes it (9 choose 5)^9 = 126^9 = 8.00451285e18 which is a really big number..
For some reason that seems wrong...any help?
I am using choose since the arrangment of the odd number is irrelvant because the two placments on the attached image gives the same result
[image]

Comment: As far as I have understood your question, the position of the odd numbers is irrelevant but they can be placed only on black tiles. Since you have 5 odd numbers and 5 black tiles this leads to (5 choose 5) = 1. I am pretty sure that this is not what you are asking about and I have not understand your question correctly. Could please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Yes, inside a section of 3X3 out of the whole board (which is 9X9)
the odd number can be arranged in any order i.e. they have 3*3=9 places they can "go" to however placing between their places is irrelevant since presumably they have the same "color" and so the two different position up here yields the same board image.